# Adding my own UIElement control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have always programmed in C# procedural code, not in XAML, but now, due to team working i have to use XAML, but I need to add my custom controls. I have the controls in both ways:

I can add the classes to the project or I can use my DLL where are the components.
If I copy and paste the classes which contains my components, I will have a class for each components:

```
class FXGrid
class FXListBox
class FXButton
class FXPanel
```

etc

But now, how do I add my components in XAML so I can view them in the visual editor?

If I add the DLL, do I just add the reference and create an `xmlns:MyGrid="..."` ?
I tried but I can't get it working. Do I need to change something?
Thanks.

Comment: have a look..... http://www.wpftutorial.net/howtocreateacustomcontrol.html

Comment: _"do I just add the reference and create an xmlns:MyGrid="...""_ -- yes, that should work. Of course, you need to qualify the type name in the XAML with the XML namespace `MyGrid`, e.g. `<MyGrid:MyGridControl ...>`. Frankly, the question is addressed in a number of easily-found places, including MSDN and various tutorials on the Internet. If you feel that the question really deserves answering here, you need to provide enough detail so that someone can figure out what you've done wrong. See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird, *but in my case* this was fixed by adding the XAML DLL assembly reference like this:

```
xmlns:FxComps="clr-namespace:FxComps;assembly=FxComps"
```

Don't know why, but adding `assembly=FxComps` fixed my problem, now I can use it.

Comment: It's not weird at all, that is how it is supposed to work. An arbitrary  namespace can exist in multiple assemblies, hence why you need to specify the external assembly name.